# Use luatex to \let command to other

Tags: macros, luatex

still looking for LuaTeX, I understand how I can execute Lua code insided TeX code (via `\luadirect`) but not how I could execute TeX code inside Lua code.

I explain : I would like to make a series of \let command from a luatex list.

My MWE is

```
\def\a{s}

\directlua{
  x = {"b","c"}
  for y in pairs(x) do
    print (y)
    % I would like to \let\<y>\a
  end
}
```

What I would like it that \directlua produce something like

```
\let\b\a
\let\c\a
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can probably mess directly with TeX's hash table from lua but simpler is just to get lua to write out the `\let` statements.

```
> \b=macro:
->s.
l.10 \show\b

? 
> \c=macro:
->s.
l.11 \show\c

? 
)
No pages of output
```

Produced from:

```
\def\a{s}

\directlua{
  x = {"b","c"}
  for n,y in pairs(x) do
     tex.print("\string\\let\string\\" .. y .. "\string\\a")
  end
}

\show\b
\show\c

\bye
```